# Gettin error when running simple php script

Tags: php

I'm trying to run this simple script:

```
<?php

$PHP_PATH = "c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\\";
$CLIENTPATH = dirname(__FILE__)."\Client.php";
$SERVER = "http://localhost:8080/mobile/Server";

$handle = popen("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd /C start ".$PHP_PATH." -f ".$CLIENTPATH." ".$SERVER, 'r');

?>
```

But I always get this Windows messagebox error:

```
Windows cannot find c:\program. Please make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again.
```

Searching on google I also find this [thread](http://forums.whatthetech.com/index.php?showtopic=87483) about this error, but the meassures are I litlle drastic I guess.
So the problem its in my code ? Or there can be something else wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the whitespaces in `$PHP_PATH = "c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\\";`!

Comment: and can u also tell me how ? I dont normally program in php , thanks

Comment: @vBx `addcslashes($path, ' ')`

Comment: @Linus Kleen: I did this addcslashes($PHP_PATH, ' '); after PHP_PATH, but still getting the same error

Comment: Ok. I'm spelling it out: `$PHP_PATH = addcslashes($PHP_PATH, ' ')`. Optionally, you can enclose the path in quotes (i.e. `popen("C:\... '".$PHP_PATH."' -f ...")`).